# Shell sort only 3 times faster than Bubble sort?

Tags: c, shellsort

I have implemented Shell sort in C and it only about 3 times faster than Bubble sort.
Here are my sorting durations in seconds:

```
For list of 100 integers:
BubbleSort: 0.000333
ShakeSort: 0.000282
QuickSort: 0.000048
QuickSort_Iter: 0.000063
InsertionSort: 0.000188
ShellSort: 0.000150

For list of 1000 integers:
BubbleSort: 0.028191
ShakeSort: 0.019354
QuickSort: 0.000435
QuickSort_Iter: 0.000528
InsertionSort: 0.011917
ShellSort: 0.003664

For list of 5000 integers:
BubbleSort: 0.241116
ShakeSort: 0.222127
QuickSort: 0.001306
QuickSort_Iter: 0.001592
InsertionSort: 0.151656
ShellSort: 0.091002

For list of 10000 integers:
BubbleSort: 0.959580
ShakeSort: 0.872648
QuickSort: 0.002877
QuickSort_Iter: 0.003379
InsertionSort: 0.601329
ShellSort: 0.350866
```

It it normal or is it likely a problem with my implementation?

Comment: It depends hugely on your dataset

Comment: it's array-based vector of pseudo-random integers 0-999. I'm just wondering if it at all reasonable performance for Shell sort, under any condition

Comment: There's no such thing as "any" condition. Condition really matters... imagine you have a completely sorted array of numbers except for the first and the last one which are swapped: in that case, shell sort is likely to be faster than bubble sort (since it can do one swap, while bubble sort would have to swap all numbers)... but that's just one edge case: it doesn't mean that bubble sort is slower or faster than shell sort, it only means that for that specific dataset. The `n` in the big O matters, a lot :-)

Comment: The algorithm is not "3 times faster". Bubble-sort has `O(n)` to `O(n*n)` complexity, while shell-sort has `O(n*log n)` to `O(n*log n*log n)` complexity. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellsort and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort. But these are "asymptotic complexity", real number depends on implementation details though they tend to the asymptotic complexity.

Comment: Repeat mesurements for 1000000 elements.

Comment: I have a sort benchmarking program with 4 variants of shell sort and bubble sort built in. Three of the four variants have similar timing properties; the fourth is dramatically worse than the other three. However, when the sort size is 1000, the 3 shell sorts take less than 100µs while the slow one takes less than 600µs and bubble sort takes less than 900µs, but at size 10,000, the times vary between 1-2ms vs 70ms vs 142ms, and at size 100,000, the times vary between 14-30ms vs 8.6s vs 18s. Thus, one of the shell sorts is about half the speed of bubble sort, but the others are way better.

Comment: Ok, I changed the implementation, using Insertion sort logic to sort sub-vectors during Shell sort, so now it performs as expected

Comment: Please post the results of this modification. I you have the time, try the set of gaps I provided in my answer (below).

Answer (score 1):

I would say it is a "problem" with your implementation.

The tricky thing with shellsort is that for a given sequence of n values to be sorted, there is a single set of gaps that will cause shellsort to - for the average case - outperform all other sets of gaps - or standard algorithms for that matter*. Less good sets of gaps will result in lackluster or even poor performance.

Sequences from Knuth, Sedgewick, Ciura and others are not that good but let's face it, finding the best set of gaps given n is a mammoth task, considering how comparatively little we know about the algorithm's secrets.

Evaluating sets of gaps to find the best one is tricky (especially for large sets of values) as I wrote about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539545/fastest-gap-sequence-for-shell-sort/50490873#50490873).

- Tested for sets of values where n<=16

___________________ EDIT ___________________

I propose you try the following set of gaps for n=100: {99,60,16,4,1} that I think will improve your 100-integer shellsort results.

Answer (score 0):

I have a sort benchmarking program with 4 variants of shell sort and bubble sort built in. Three of the four variants have similar timing properties; the fourth is dramatically worse than the other three. However, when the sort size is 1000, the 3 shell sorts take less than 100µs while the slow one takes less than 600µs and bubble sort takes less than 900µs, but at size 10,000, the times vary between 1-2ms vs 70ms vs 142ms, and at size 100,000, the times vary between 14-30ms vs 8.6s vs 18s. Thus, one of the shell sorts is about half the speed of bubble sort, but the others are way better. – Jonathan Leffler

Ok, I changed the implementation, using Insertion sort logic to sort sub-vectors during Shell sort, so now it performs as expected – LynnXe